# DAG-oriented git browser?

Tags: git, client, directed-acyclic-graphs

There are git intros with [pretty](http://marklodato.github.com/visual-git-guide/index-en.html) [graphs](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/) to get your head around the concept of "git's history is just a DAG". I'm wondering why there are (seemingly) few visual git browsers that builds upon this exact model for representing the history.

- [git-cola's DAG view](http://cola.tuxfamily.org/screenshots.html) (Looks like still an experimental feature)
- [github's network graph](https://github.com/blog/39-say-hello-to-the-network-graph-visualizer) (Quite close to what I'm looking for, but it's not a standalone tool)

Other than these, all of the visual git browsers (gitk, git-gui, GitX, etc.) push aside the graph to a narrow column in favor of textual information.

Is there a git repo browser that has the DAG view as the main feature? Any platform, any language, standalone, GUI/CUI doesn't matter.

I'm not looking to solve a specific problem at hand. Just hoping a radical tool may help me reach the git zen.

**Edit:** related but, in OP's view, different questions:

- [Pretty git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs)

I'm looking for more than "a tool to generate a git history DAG"; like a web browser, this hypothetical "DAG-oriented git browser" should be able to view, search, jump and filter the history graph.

Comment: So is what you are looking for merely a graph view that does not squeeze the branches (like gitk)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057564/pretty-git-branch-graphs

Comment: @user611775 Maybe yes. I'm not sure what's required to augment the DAG to a usable repo browser, but if there is such a thing, I'd like to know of it.

Comment: @bta Thanks for the pointer. This question has a slightly different angle I think, which I added back to the question body.

Comment: git-cola's DAG is very basic, like initial-implementation basic. I couldn't find much by way of ref scope settings (e.g. adding an `--all` flag), nor arrangement or view options other than the +/- zoom buttons (and by default set to a zoom level that makes me wonder if the dev responsible is legally blind).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ungit](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit) is a new tool that I'd been waiting for for a while, one which lets you view and manipulate git repositories by dragging around nodes in the commit DAG.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a general purpose tool but I use a small script to do this which uses `graphviz` to do the actual graphing.

It doesn't work very well for huge graphs. I mostly use it when I do git trainings rather than to visualise my own projects. You might be able to 
tweak it for your purposes.

It's available [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577572-display-a-git-repository/?in=lang-ruby).

Comment: I've made my improvements to this script available on github.  See [my answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10973682/47552) for more.

Answer (score 1):

git-forest, a non-squeezing graph tool (`git log --graph --oneline`, but uses Unicode's line drawing characters instead which makes for a more connected tree). [Screenshot](http://i55.tinypic.com/b3mrde.png).

Comment: Found here: [git-forest](https://github.com/jwiegley/git-scripts/blob/master/git-forest). Cool! Launching `gitk --all` was so overkill

Answer (score 1):

[gitup](http://gitup.co/) is a great tool to visualize and manipulate git history as a graph

[image]